# zoom on drowing objects

Tags: java, android, object, zooming, draw

I have actitivity, where I drawing objects (circles) on definied positions. But I want make zoom for this view. For example, when I draw circle (50, 50, 10) on display with HD resolution, and I zoom it on 200%, this circle should by don´t visible. And when I zoom out, back to 100%, circle should by back on 50,50 positions. Is it possible ? Thanks for your help. Simply, I need to draw objects to correct position, after zooming. I think, I should use scaling drawing position, or use matrix on canvas.